# select_by_visible text not working properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have this following block of code which allows me to successfully retrieve every value of a dropdown box:

```
def extract_sct_projects(driver, base_url):
    driver.get(base_url)
    driver.find_element_by_id('dropdown_id').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('list_of_objects')
    select = Select(element)
    for o in select.options:
        print o.get_attribute("text")

base_url = 'http://localhost'
phantom_js = 'C:\\phantomjs-2.0.0\\bin\\phantomjs.exe'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantom_js)

extract_sct_projects(driver, base_url)
```

But when i try to select one of the values by using the text of each field using:

```
for o in select.options:
    select.select_by_visible_text(o.get_attribute("text"))
```

The following error shows:

```
"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"
```

What could i be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move to the element before selecting it:

```
for option in select.options:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", option)
    select.select_by_visible_text(option.get_attribute("text"))
```

Or using `mouseMove()` action:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
for option in select.options:
    actions.move_to_element(option).perform()
    select.select_by_visible_text(option.get_attribute("text"))
```

Comment: both examples didn't worked, mouseMove works for PhantonJS ?

Comment: @Thales okay, can you try the same code with Chrome or Firefox? Also, can you share a link to the website you are testing it against?

Comment: The problem is related on the website ( i cant share the link).

I just tested with : http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown and my code works perfectly. i'm going to investigate what could be on our html side

Comment: i have no idea what happened... suddenly started to work :\.

Should i delete this question?

Comment: @Thales okay, go ahead. Thanks.